# Multi-project pipeline with trigger , example from the gitlab docs doesn't work

Tags: triggers, gitlab-ci, pipeline

The example for the multi project pipeline with mirroring status ( https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/multi_project_pipelines.html#mirroring-status-from-triggered-pipeline) doesn't work:

```yaml
trigger_job:
  trigger:
    project: my/project
    strategy: depend
```

Leads to an error:
"This GitLab CI configuration is invalid: jobs:trigger_pipeline_in_another_repo config contains unknown keys: trigger"

config:

```yaml
trigger_pipeline_in_another_repo:
  stage: trigger_pipeline_in_b
  script:
    - apt-get update && apt-get upgrade -y
    - apt-get install curl -y
    - curl --request POST --form "token=$CI_JOB_TOKEN" --form ref=master http://35.184.231.241/api/v4/projects/8/trigger/pipeline
  trigger:
    project: root/isolated_pipeline
    strategy: depend
```

Comment: Note that `trigger` can't be used with `script`. You'll have to comment it out. [Source][https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/209255?__cf_chl_jschl_tk__=pmd_9sMkpdizR.zMxLK9U7L9FgSa7V1I3y7dfGbdnobAHvA-1631631107-0-gqNtZGzNAjujcnBszQf9]

Answer (score 3):

`Multi-project pipelines` are only supported for paid versions.

> Introduced in GitLab Premium 9.3.
>
> Available in GitLab Premium, GitLab.com Silver, and higher tiers

If you use free GitLab Enterprise Edition then trigger is not supported in it.

You can check your Gitlab version by going to help page `<Gitlab url>/help`